# How to run FreePBX for the first time?

Tags: java, freepbx, asterisk-java

I'm new to FreePBX, I followed info here : https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java/wiki/Getting-Started

And my settings class looks like this :

```
package org.asteriskjava.examples.activities;

import org.asteriskjava.pbx.DefaultAsteriskSettings;

public class MyAsteriskSettings extends DefaultAsteriskSettings
{
  @Override
  public String getManagerPassword()
  {
    return [ my password ];                                                             // this password MUST match the password (secret=) in manager.conf
  }

  @Override
  public String getManagerUsername()
  {
    return "admin";                                                                     // this MUST match the section header '[myconnection]' in manager.conf
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsteriskIP()
  {
    return "10.2.3.158";                                                               // The IP address or FQDN of your Asterisk server.

  }

  @Override
  public String getAgiHost()
  {
    return "127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0";                                                   // The IP Address of FQDN of you asterisk-java application.
  }
}
```

My class for "once off initialisation of the PBXFactory" looks like this :

```
package org.asteriskjava.examples.activities;

import org.asteriskjava.pbx.PBXFactory;
import org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.AsteriskPBX;
import org.asteriskjava.util.Log;
import org.asteriskjava.util.LogFactory;

public class Init_PBX_Factory
{
  static private Log logger=LogFactory.getLog(Init_PBX_Factory.class);

  static public void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      PBXFactory.init(new MyAsteriskSettings());                             // Initialise the PBX Factory. You need to implement your own AsteriskSettings class.
      AsteriskPBX asteriskPbx=(AsteriskPBX)PBXFactory.getActivePBX();        // Activities utilise an agi entry point in your dial plan. You can create your own
      asteriskPbx.createAgiEntryPoint();                                     // entry point in dialplan or have asterisk-java add it automatically as we do here.    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      logger.error("Failed to Init_PBX_Factory : ",e);
    }
  }
}
```

But after I ran " Init_PBX_Factory", I got the following error :

```
Oct 09, 2019 2:32:04 PM org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.AsteriskPBX <init>
SEVERE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.managerAPI.Connector.checkIfAsteriskRunning(Connector.java:64)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.managerAPI.Connector.connect(Connector.java:38)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.CoherentManagerConnection.configureConnection(CoherentManagerConnection.java:390)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.CoherentManagerConnection.<init>(CoherentManagerConnection.java:172)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.CoherentManagerConnection.init(CoherentManagerConnection.java:123)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.AsteriskPBX.<init>(AsteriskPBX.java:92)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.AsteriskPBX.<clinit>(AsteriskPBX.java:77)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.PBXFactory.getActivePBX(PBXFactory.java:12)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.PBXFactory.init(PBXFactory.java:21)
  at org.asteriskjava.examples.activities.Init_PBX_Factory.main(Init_PBX_Factory.java:17)

java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.AsteriskPBX.performPostCreationTasks(AsteriskPBX.java:118)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.PBXFactory.init(PBXFactory.java:21)
  at org.asteriskjava.examples.activities.Init_PBX_Factory.main(Init_PBX_Factory.java:17)
Oct 09, 2019 2:32:04 PM org.asteriskjava.examples.activities.Init_PBX_Factory main
SEVERE: Failed to Init_PBX_Factory :
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.internal.core.AsteriskPBX.performPostCreationTasks(AsteriskPBX.java:118)
  at org.asteriskjava.pbx.PBXFactory.init(PBXFactory.java:21)
  at org.asteriskjava.examples.activities.Init_PBX_Factory.main(Init_PBX_Factory.java:17)
```

What did I do wrong, how to fix it ?

Comment: `SEVERE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` suggests its a connection issue.

Answer (score 1):

In class `MyAsteriskSettings` add the following method:

```
  @Override
public int getManagerPortNo() {
    return 5038;
}
```

Comment: Got this : Nov 22, 2019 8:02:10 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl connect
INFO: Connecting to 10.2.3.158:5038
Nov 22, 2019 8:02:10 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
INFO: Connected via Asterisk Call Manager/2.10.4
Nov 22, 2019 8:02:10 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
WARNING: Unsupported protocol version 'Asterisk Call Manager/2.10.4'. Use at your own risk.
Nov 22, 2019 8:02:11 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl disconnect
INFO: Closing socket.